# How to pass a tuple from Python 3.6 to C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x

Small issue with full embedded `Python` and `C++`. The question is that I have a `Python` code that will return a tuple, aka in this case the statement is:

```
def test():
   x = 1;
   y=2;
   c=3;
   d=4;
   return [x,y,c,d]
```

In `C++`, I have embedded the code in the following fashion:

```
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
Py_DECREF(pArgs);
if (pValue != NULL)
{
    printf("Result of call: %d\n", PyTuple_GetItem(pArgs, i, pValue));
}
```

For some reason, printed output is something like this:

Result of call: `1846660304`

Tried also returning a string, this did not work either. Only one that worked was returning for example return h and the in `C++` instead of using `PyTuple_GetItem`, use `PyLong_AsLong()`.

Can someone please point me to the correct direction in how to read he return values to `C++`, I'm rather new to `Python` and unfortunately the `Python` documentation is on a poor level at least in this case with no code samples or anything whatsoever.

Comment: This is a _list_, not a tuple. I'd guess `PyTuple_GetItem` returns a memory address of a variable, not its actual value.

Comment: Yes ok, but how to actually treat that in C++ aka how to extract the data? Or to put it in other words, what would be the best way to pass multiple arguments from the python script to C++ and how to extract the data?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html

Comment: You should compile with stricter warnings, you want to get an error when you try to print a pointer using the `%d` format.

Comment: Yes bu I really have no idea what to do, how to "compile with stricter warnings" (using visual studio 2017). Anyways I changed the code to

def test():
      x = 1;
      y=2;
      c=3;
      d=4;
      return (x,y,c,d)

Answer (score 2):

You have four issues:

- your function is returning a `list`, not a `tuple`.  Using `PyTuple_GetItem` is inappropriate; and
- `PyTuple_GetItem` does not take three arguments, it takes only two; and
- since you cannot be sure of the return type in any case, you would be better to use `PyObject_GetItem`; and
- most importantly, *you are looking in the wrong object*.

That is, you are using `PyTuple_GetItem(pArgs, i, pValue)`, which will be attempting to look in `pArgs`.  You presumably what to access `pValue`:

```
PyObject_GetItem(pValue, i)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as per your suggestion, the result was that the whole executable crashes :( Just-In-Time debugger says uncaught exception at that line with the printf. I also tried with PyObject_GetItem(pValue, 0) but same result...

Comment: In addition, `PyObject_GetItem` will give you another `PyObject*` (representing an integer), which cannot be passed to `printf` like a C integer.

Comment: Hmm ok I understand; how to pass it correctly to printf? Bottomline is I just need to get the return values from Python into variables in C++ and I just have no idea how to do it. The Python documentation with zero code examples is not of much use.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple and the example at https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html which is pretty much the same only for a string.

Comment: I really honestly don't know but Jeronimo you said that there is an example for how to do that same for a string on that page docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html. I read thru it twice and just cannot find which of the examples you mean?

Comment: @aalamaki ... `PyObject_GetItem` returns you a `PyObject*`.  If you *know* its a number (better check) then you can get its c-equivalent using eg [PyLong_AsLong](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLong)

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is surrounded by (1,2,3,4), not brackets. Try changing the tuple in the Py code and then re-running your code.